# fish: how to do a membership test?

Tags: membership, fish

I'm trying to write a function that boots all my vagrant machines at once. I want to exclude specific IDs. How I can check for membership in `fish`?

```
function test_me
        # this this the array to check against
        set exclude "0a964df" "6a8ab7b" "ebe9620"
        set test (vagrant global-status | grep stop | cut -c1-7);
        for entry in $test
            # if $entry in $exclude - how do I do this?
            vagrant up $entry --no-provision;
        end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [`contains`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#contains) command.

```
for entry in $test
    if not contains $entry $exclude
        vagrant up $entry --no-provision
    end
end
```